How to Programmatically Open Two Apps in **Full Screen** Split View?
Many discussions and solutions exist for programmatically opening two apps in the default desktop, including Rectangle, Tiles, Moom, and many AppleScripts. I have tried them all, and none of them is truly full-screen. What I want is to achieve either of the two below manual processes programmatically:
(say I want Safari on the left and Google Chrome on the right)

Start Safari => Enter Full Screen Mode on Safari => Start Google Chrome => Enter Full Screen Mode on Google Chrome => Triple Swipe Up/Ctrl+Up for Mission Control => Manually Drag the Safari Full Screen into =

Start Safari => Hover over the green dot and click on "Tile Window to the Left of the Screen" => Use the mouse to identify and select the Google Chrome window among the Mission Control-like mini-windows on the right pane.


Currently, none of the third-party apps I have tried are able to achieve this outside of the default desktop. Here's the AppleScript I've developed in an attempt to simulate the #2 route, but
set leftApp to "Safari"
set rightApp to "Google Chrome"

tell application leftApp to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process leftApp
        click menu item "Tile Window to Left of Screen" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
        -- Execution is stuck here for a mouse selection of Google Chrome window. The rest of the script is not executed.
    end tell
    delay 0.5 -- a shorter value will probably work
    tell application rightApp to activate
    tell process rightApp
        tell application rightApp to get bounds of window 1
        click button 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

The error is System Events got an error: Can't get application "Google Chrome" of process "Google Chrome". I suspect this is because the "Tile Window to Left of Screen" awaits a manual clicking process for Mission Control-like windows and blocks the rest of the code from executing.
